# How to process form with ajax in smarty

Tags: ajax, smarty

I am stick with smarty template to process form with ajax it should not reload page...

anyone here to show me the write way if need i will post the code also.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For example, start here:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/wa-aj-smarty/index.html?ca=drs-

Comment: Thanks, it's for processing the file into div with ajax... I have knowladge of it ... just i am trying to get data from form and process it via ajax without loading page.

Comment: That you need to do in the browser with JavaScript. You can prepare the ajax request with http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ and on response refresh the div with HTML generated on the server side with Smarty.